# Проверка на существующую запись

Tags: mysqli, php

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста делаю страницу просмотра профиля, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, get запрос у меня таков profile.php?user_info=$id(ид пользователя которого хочу просмотреть) как мне сделать проверку на существующий ид, то есть иными словами если нету такого пользователя который посетитель сайта напишет в запросе get к к примеру profile.php?user_info=10, то мы его перекидываем к примеру... Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо большое...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['user_info']))
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT nickname, status FROM users WHERE id =   ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['user_info']));
    if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        //выводим здесь инфо о пользователе
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['nickname']; 
            echo $row['status'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // такого юзверя не существует, делаем что-нибудб другое
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

$id желательно прогонять через фильтр перед вставкой в запрос, чтобы не получить sql-инъекцию

```
$q = query("select name,info from users where id = '".(int)$id."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($q) != 0){
   выводим инфу о пользователе
}
else{
   выдаём ошибку что такой пользователь не существует.
}
```